# GNUStep setup error

Tags: gnustep

I am a beginner in objective-C and trying to setup GNUStep in Windows 7.
I have followed the direction in this site:
http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html
to download GNUstep MSYS System 0.30.0,GNUstep Core 0.30.0 ,GNUstep Devel,and GNUstep Cairo.
However, when I run the installer, no package can be selected to installed, and after that, I cant find the shell to start.
Btw,I got Cygwin installed on my lap. 
How to fix that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bad answer. But without enough experience, I'd suggest you to stay away from GNUstep on Windows. For your learning purpose a GNU/Linux live CD with a removable drive mounted to /home and /usr/local could be a friendlier solution. While that you can figure out how to properly install the system on Windows. There has been not much effort to do that and that's why newer systems aren't well tested, newer system like clang and other things necessary for Objective-C 2.0, as I bet you wouldn't want to stick with old dialect like some others.